# Angular: issue with scopes/factory values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, ionic-framework, factory

I'm starting to use the AngularJS framework, the fact is I need the same scope in different views and, as I can understand, all the scopes in a controller are reinitialized in each view.

I read some manuals, and I found a solution by using "factories", these allows to you to have persisting data in different views. But, I may be using factories in an incorrect way because after the controller function, I need a new view and the value there didn't change...

My app.js file:

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
var valid_numbers = ["2222","7777","8888","9999"];

qrApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

 .factory("Scannresult", function(){

   var interfaz= {
     data: "Not information"
   };
   return interfaz;
 })

  .controller("qrController", function($scope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner, Scannresult) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    $scope.result=Scannresult.data;
    $scope.scanBarcode = function() {
        $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(successCallback, errorCallback);
        }});

    errorCallback = function (error) {
    alert("An error happened -> " + error);
    };
    successCallback= function(imageData){
              $scope.result=Scannresult.data;

        var index = valid_numbers.indexOf(imageData.text);    //chequea si el numero encontrado es valido
      if (index >= 0) {
        alert("El código " + imageData.text + " es valido! :D");
        alert("Factory = " + Scannresult.data);
        Scannresult.data = imageData.text;
        $scope.result=Scannresult.data;

        alert("1 El Scope es " + Scannresult.data);
        alert("2 El Scope es " + $scope.result);
        $scope.$apply();
                alert("2.1 El Scope es " + $scope.result);

        if (imageData.cancelled) alert("Volve a internarlo!");
        else
          window.location = "Scannresult.html";
      } else {
        alert("El código encontrado no es valido: " + imageData.text);
      }
    }
});
```

In this code, what I need is after scan, the value of `$scope.result` was displayed in Scannresult.html, but in this file, the scope has it initial value.

Scannresult.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Resultado</title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
  <div ng-controller="qrController">
    <div class="list card">
    <div class="item item-avatar">
    <h2>Información del código</h2>
    <h2>   escaneado</h2>
    <p>Aula: {{ result }}</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item item-image">
    <img src="img/aula.png">
  </div>

  <a class="item item-icon-left assertive" ng-click="scanBarcode()" href="#">
    <i class="icon ion-music-note"></i>
Volver a escanear  </a>

</div>  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use factories, and then dependency inject them into your controller, this allows you to resolve a shared instance you can work with across many controllers.

If you are looking for a simple way to access data or variables across multiple scopes or pages, you can, with care use `$rootScope`.

For example, assignment of `$rootScope.test = true` would resolve `true` on `$rootScope.test` on any controller you attempt to resolve it on.

Use this judiciously however, as you do not want to pollute or clutter your $rootScope as it is, as mentioned available to any controller.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I finnaly used the same view that calls the function.